# what design should my Fixture table should have in order to select and show Two teams from Drop Down List?

Tags: sql-server

**Team** table

```
   TeamID (PK)
   TeamName 
   CoachID  (FK)
```

**Fixture** Table

```
 FixtureID  (PK)
 Venue    
 Team1    (FK) to TeamTable
 Team2     (FK) to TeamTable
 FixtureDate
```

I have created a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_Fixture_SelectAll]
AS
    SELECT
        [dbo].[Fixture].[FixtureID],
        [dbo].[Fixture].[Venue],
        [dbo].[Fixture].[Team1],
        [dbo].[Fixture].[Team2],
        [dbo].[Fixture].[FixtureDate],
        [dbo].[Team].[TeamName]
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Fixture] 
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Team] ON [dbo].[Team].[TeamID] = [dbo].[Fixture].[Team1]
    INNER JOIN
        [dbo].[Team] t ON[dbo].[Team].[TeamID] = [dbo].[Fixture].[Team2]
```

The stored procedure when executed shows only column name and not the data inserted

Comment: FYI, including the schema name when referencing a column is deprecated and should be avoided. You're best off using aliases for your tables. As for why there is no data, I assume because there were no relevant rows, or the `JOIN` failed. With no sample data, and expected results, impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
DECLARE @Team TABLE
(
   TeamID INT  ,
   TeamName VARCHAR(50),
   CoachID INT 
)

DECLARE @Fixture Table
(

    FixtureID INT,
    Venue VARCHAR(50),
    Team1 INT ,
    Team2 INT,
    FixtureDate DATE

)

INSERT INTO @Team(TeamID,TeamName,CoachID) VALUES(1,'A',1)
INSERT INTO @Team(TeamID,TeamName,CoachID) VALUES(2,'B',2)
INSERT INTO @Team(TeamID,TeamName,CoachID) VALUES(3,'C',3)
INSERT INTO @Team(TeamID,TeamName,CoachID) VALUES(4,'D',4)

INSERT INTO @Fixture(FixtureID,Venue,Team1,Team2,FixtureDate) VALUES(1,'X',1,3,GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @Fixture(FixtureID,Venue,Team1,Team2,FixtureDate) VALUES(2,'Y',2,4,GETDATE())

SELECT
        f.FixtureID,
        f.Venue,
        t1.TeamName Team1,
        t2.TeamName Team2,
        f.FixtureDate
FROM @Fixture f
Inner Join @Team t1 ON  f.Team1 = t1.TeamID 
Inner Join @Team t2 ON  f.Team2 = t2.TeamID
```

[image]